# How to charge card on clicking accept button in stripe in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal-7, payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I am using stripe and trying to charge card by clicking on accept button.
    I have already created charge and created customer.
and now trying to create charge by clicking accept button.

Please suggest me the way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<?php
    function payment_show()
     {
     include ('config.inc');

     include ('charge.inc');
    ?>
    <?php
     $code = db_query("SELECT * FROM {stripe_payment}");
    ?>
      <table border='1'>
    <th>ID</th><th>Payment ID</th><th>Customer ID</th><th>Customer Email</th><th>Payment Amount</th><th>Payment Date</th><th>Refund</th><th>Accept</th>
    <?php
     foreach($code as $codes)
      {
       
       //$ch = StripeCharge::retrieve($Payment_id);
       $ch = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve($codes->payment_id);

    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $codes->Id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $codes->payment_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $codes->customer_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $codes->customer_email; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $codes->payment_amount; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $codes->payment_date; ?></td>
    <td><a href="https://dashboard.stripe.com/payments/<?php echo $codes->payment_id; ?>">Refund</a></td><td><strike> <input type="button" value="Accept"  onclick="document.write('<?php $ch->capture(); ?>');" />    </strike></td></tr>
    <?php
      }

    ?>
      </table>
      <?php
     }

    ?>
```

```js
$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
                    
              $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                  'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail'],
                  'card'  => $token
              ));
            
           
        
           $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                  'customer' => $customer->id,
                  'amount'   => 5000,
                  'currency' => 'usd',
                  'capture'  => false
              ))

    ;

 $ch = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve($codes->payment_id);
          $ch->capture();
```